# Find Unmatch record 2 table with where condition apply and record show from 1 table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

class table

- class_code    varchar(50)
- timing    varchar(50)
- emp_id    varchar(50)

employee table

- i_id  int
- emp_id    varchar(20)
- name  varchar(50)

  1. We Have 2 tables 1 is employee and other is class
  2. we have 4 records in employee table where emp_id=as-1,as-2,as-3,as-4
  3. we have 2 records in class table with emp_id = as-1 or as-3 and timing= '3-4'

We select those record from employee table who available/free at timing='3-4' like as-2 or as-3 because as-1 or as-3 is already in class table in timing at 3-4

Comment: Which DBMS you have mysql or SQL-Server. Please remove the wrong tags!

Comment: why have emp_id as varchar(20) in one table but varchar(50) in another

Comment: i use SQL SERVER 2008 and emp_id varchar(20) on both table

Comment: we have 3 employee and their emp_id is e-1,e-2,e-3 on employee table ok now the e-1,e-2 is worked in 3-4 and e-3 is free their record in class table now we select the record of employee with condition where timing=3-4 but i want the record who free at 3-4 like e-3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not told us a great deal and the indicated data may not be fully representative. Both of these will return employee 2 and 4 (&  both will work in MySQL or MSsql):

```
SELECT
      e.*
FROM employee e
      LEFT JOIN class c
            ON e.emp_id = c.emp_id
WHERE (c.timing <> '3-4'
      OR c.timing IS NULL)
;

SELECT
      *
FROM employee
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM class
            WHERE timing = '3-4'
                  AND class.emp_id = employee.emp_id
      )
;
```

see [this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/08b40/4) (MySQL)

Comment: Example: we have 3 employee and their emp_id is e-1,e-2,e-3 on employee table ok now the e-1,e-2 is worked in 3-4 and e-3 is free their record in class table  now we select the record of employee with condition where timing=3-4 but i want the record who free at 3-4 like e-3